# Local Development Image Path Not Working for Carrierwave on Rails & STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, development-environment

I am trying to upload locally using CarrierWave (for development).  My file uploads and saves to

```
 /public/uploads/news_page/hero_img/#{model.id}
```

However, when I try to call this image in the view I get this path:

```
No route matches [GET] "/uploads/news_page/hero_img/13/7388aa89cc3aef55b4de707420fcd1d7.jpeg"
```

But that IS where the image is and it is stored by that name in the database (just the image name).  I don't know why it's showing a broken image in the view.

view.rb

```
figure
  = image_tag @page.hero_img, alt: 'hero'
```

hero_img_uploader.rb

```
class HeroImgUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 include CarrierWave::RMagick
 CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
 # storage :fog
 include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
 process :set_content_type

  storage :file unless Rails.env == "production"
  # storage :fog unless Rails.env == "development"
  # storage :fog unless Rails.env == "test"
  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

 # def store_dir
 #  "pages/#{model.id}/hero/"
 # end

# Process files as they are uploaded:
  process :resize_to_limit => [1500, 500]

  version :md do
    process :resize_to_limit => [900, 300]
  end

  version :sm do
    process :resize_to_limit => [420, 140]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename 
    if original_filename 
      @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
      "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end

end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.


  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  config.serve_static_files = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Configurations for MailCatcher
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 5000 }

  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
  end


end
```

relevant routes from "rake routes"

```
pages           GET    /pages(.:format)                       pages#index
                POST   pages(.:format)                        pages#create
new_page        GET    pages/new(.:format)                    pages#new
edit_page       GET    pages/:id/edit(.:format)               pages#edit
page            GET    pages/:id(.:format)                    pages#show
PATCH  pages/:id(.:format)                                    pages#update
PUT    pages/:id(.:format)                                    pages#update
```

Comment: Please provide your `config/development.rb` file.

Comment: I added the developgment.rb file....I should mention I'm using port:5000 and not port:3000.  That's not set in the dev file....I don't know if it should be.

Comment: Could you please provide your result of "rake routes" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed! Just change this line:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

To this one:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

In your `config/development.rb` file.

Probably you changed in unintentionally before (in `production` environment it makes sense because you have another server to serve assets, e.g. nginx or Apache).